# Black screen / No audio running 20.04 with AMd Ryzen & Radeon RX 580

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, 20.04, sound, amd-graphics

Will try to be brief, but detailed. Prior to a roughly three month hiatus, I ran updates via terminal and shut down my dual boot, external drive Ubuntu installation & when I recently booted into Ubuntu, I got a black login screen. I booted into recovery and updated grub with "amdgpu.dc=0". This fix leaves me with no audio - this was intended to be a quick fix just to login, since I am unsure what the amdgpu.dc flag actually accomplishes.

After this adjustment, the Radeon RX 580 and HDMI audio output are recognized in settings but still no audio and the login screen is just video artifacts, not the standard screen.  I was able to reach the desktop environment.

I tried a fresh install, but the "live cd" USB drive would not complete a fresh installation and there was no audio during the installation process. The USB Live CD drive/key does work on another AMD notebook that I have, so the issue is not bad bits or bad USB key. This leads be to believe that the kernel or current AMD driver is the issue, since my PC functioned normally only a few months ago and I originally installed 20.04.1 using a live cd without issue.

I have the latest kernel but installed/booted into the original release kernel for testing, with no improvement. To confirm, the graphics and audio worked fine via HDMI prior to about six months ago. I have been unable to find any post that fully addresses this issue and believe that the open source drivers may not work with either my motherboard or the Radeon RX 580 using HDMI.

Any help resolving this issue would be appreciated. Pastebin for boot repair from the initial stages of diagnostics for this issue can be found below:

````
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdc4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS CurrentSession on sda1
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sdc3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-37-generic root=UUID=772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr
df -Th / : /dev/sda1      ext4  916G  331G  539G  39% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: A.B0(5.14) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled - SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0000,0001,0008
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,63820f6f-23ea-4abd-b5ad-e9565a195245,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...3................
Boot0001  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0200)..GO..NO..........C.T.1.0.0.0.M.X.5.0.0.S.S.D.1...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.2.6.1.2.E.C.9.F.1.E.8. . . . . . . . ........BO..NO..........C.T.2.5.0.M.X.5.0.0.S.S.D.4...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A.................................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.2.8.0.2.E.D.8.9.F.C.2. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,63820f6f-23ea-4abd-b5ad-e9565a195245,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0008  USB HDD   BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0900)..GO..NO........w.I.n.a.t.e.c.k. .A.S.M.1.1.5.3.E. .0...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X..........A................................Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.1.1.1........BO


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sdb2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdc1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdc3    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdc4    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdc4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sdb2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdc1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc
sdc3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc
sdc4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 6D0A06A4-48C4-499C-B495-B2D97ACB5AD0
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1  65535 1953467279 1953401745 931.5G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: ED02BCC8-21BE-4796-818F-3F4B0806FE52
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sdb1     34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
sdb2  32768 1953521663 1953488896 931.5G Microsoft basic data
Disk sdc: 232.91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk identifier: 8F0321DF-E244-4A29-9530-4DBCF96A735A
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sdc1       2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
sdc2     206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sdc3     239616 487358580 487118965 232.3G Microsoft basic data
sdc4  487360512 488394751   1034240   505M Windows recovery environment

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:Inateck ASM1153E:;
1:33.6MB:1000GB:1000GB:ext4::;
sdb:1000GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA CT1000MX500SSD1:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdc:250GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA CT250MX500SSD4:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:250GB:249GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:250GB:250GB:530MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 0.02MiB:32.0MiB:32.0MiB
sda: 953841MiB:953870MiB:28.2MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                             
└─sda1 ext4     772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34 73825066-97b1-4450-93e8-1f6a0706c72e       
sdb                                                                                             
├─sdb1                                               ca0a7c47-4eb1-48d4-a80c-0db0661aad22       Microsoft reserved partition
└─sdb2 ntfs     06E66C25E66C1769                     247aab29-ca5f-4355-bbad-2ede395f58fa DATA  Basic data partition
sdc                                                                                             
├─sdc1 vfat     2813-663E                            63820f6f-23ea-4abd-b5ad-e9565a195245       EFI system partition
├─sdc2                                               e5dd4a19-faaa-4461-928e-5ce4a12306f9       Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdc3 ntfs     6CDE162DDE15F056                     2639a16c-79cb-4c2f-bc42-515e2d80b7e4       Basic data partition
└─sdc4 ntfs     C05247D35247CCBA                     5a865369-8d2d-4047-b45d-bfd865793b8d       

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              538.8G  36% /
/dev/sdb2              283.9G  70% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
/dev/sdc3              131.3G  43% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc3
/dev/sdc4               88.1M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc4

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1              ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=8191
/dev/sdb2              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdc3              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdc4              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-37-generic   772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-38-generic   772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34
Windows Boot Manager (on sdc1)   osprober-efi-2813-663E
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=2813-663E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 449.320189953 = 482.453880320  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 600.657908916 = 644.951518720  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  83.321940899 = 89.466252800   boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-38-generic                 2
 600.657908916 = 644.951518720  boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-37-generic                 1
  83.321940899 = 89.466252800   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 474.910365582 = 509.931122176  boot/initrd.img                                4
 685.531112194 = 736.083426816  boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-38-generic              6
 474.910365582 = 509.931122176  boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-37-generic              4
 685.531112194 = 736.083426816  boot/initrd.img.old                            6

===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18151 Aug 12  2021 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Oct  1  2020 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jul 30  2020 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jul 30  2020 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jul 30  2020 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 20 22:06 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jul 30  2020 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jul 30  2020 41_custom

=========================== sda1/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ===========================

#! /bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e
[ -d ${pkgdatadir:?} ]
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"
if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      . /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?}
      prepare_grub_to_access_device '`${grub_probe} --target=device \${ESP}` | sed -e "s/^/\t/"'
cat << EOF
    chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi

===================== sdc1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 772fdbc8-ceef-4d16-9d08-1ff152305c34 root hd2,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda1,
using the following options:  sdc1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS CurrentSession entry (sdc1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)


    2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_2b_00.4>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfc900000 irq 82"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:2b:00.4"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.4/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "1487"
        device.product.name = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_29_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 24
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcf60000 irq 80"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:29:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.2/0000:29:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "aaf0"
        device.product.name = "Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 38668, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 33568, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 33568, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_29_00.1.hdmi-stereo/#3: Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_29_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#3: Monitor of Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (priority 5400, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"```
````

Comment: What is exact Ryzen type? What is `pacmd list-cards` output? Did you try `alsamixer`?

Comment: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (6/12 Core)

pacmd list-cards in OP above (edited)

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by trying ```alsamixer``` - I can confirm that alsa audio is running and recognizes my ATi HDMI output. In the gui sound settings, the vu meter is moving during playback but there is no audio.

Comment: By adjusting ```pavucontrol``` I was able to shift audio output to the front headphone jack successfully, but had to select that output manually via gui settings. Plugging in a headset did not automatically work.

Comment: By trying `alsamixer` I meant to see its configuration for needed audio card.

Comment: When I ran ```alsamixer``` the listed card and chip were correct, but all the outputs (6) were listed as "s/pdif". Neither my graphics card nor my motherboard have a s/pdif connection. Is this correct? If not how would I correct it?

Comment: Does your working output un-muted and have output value like 100?

Comment: The numbers above the s/pdif outputs are just a small box set to "00" and attempting to adjust them using +/- keys or alternate means does not work. By comparison, when I select the on-board Realtek audio, I have a range of controls that are adjustable, including surround sound controls.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/z1CLJd6

Comment: Your `pacmd list-cards` reported `active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>`, could you please double-check if it is still the same for now?

Comment: Yes, the active profile is the same, although I have tested shifting the active profile to HDMI Digital Surround 5.1 & 7.1 - no sound, no matter which profile I activate & ```alsamixer``` shows the same screen for the HDA ATI HDMI card.

Just wanted to thank you for your continued help in troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't say anything helpful. My hardware/software configuration looks absolutely the same and sound is ok with headphones attached to HDMI monitor. Only in Settings -> Sound it automatically selects the last HDMI port. Maybe make sure that port in Settings matches to port with active profile.

Comment: In my case active profile is `output:hdmi-stereo-extra5`.

Comment: Thanks again. I have done what you suggested. I haven't tested every profile - those listed as "unplugged" will not activate.

But I have tested all active connections and matched them with the correct profile. At this point, I may try to fresh install 18.04 or even 22.04 to test after a complete wipe. I imagine that there was some monitoring software I installed that was removed or broken by unsupported dependencies.

Thanks for working through this with me!

Comment: I wish you success!